# removing unneeded code from gcc andd mingw

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

i noticed that mingw adds alot of code before calling main(), i assumed its for parsing command line parameters since one of those functions is called __getmainargs(), and also lots of strings are added to the final executable, such as mingwm.dll and some error strings (incase the app crashed) says mingw runtime error or something like that.

my question is: is there a way to remove all this stuff? i dont need all these things, i tried tcc (tiny c compiler) it did the job. but not cross platform like gcc (solaris/mac)

any ideas?

thanks.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?  If it were me, I'd probably let it be how it wants to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you really *do* need all those things. They're the startup and teardown code for the C environment that your code runs in.

Other than non-hosted environments such as low-level embedded solutions, you'll find pretty much *all* C environments have something like that. Things like `/lib/crt0.o` under some UNIX-like operating systems or `crt0.obj` under Windows.

They are vital to successful running of your code. You can freely omit library functions that you don't use (`printf`, `abs` and so on) but the startup code is needed.

---

*Some* of the things that it may perform are initialisation of `atexit` structures, argument parsing, initialisation of structures for the C runtime library, initialisation of C/C++ pre-main values and so forth.

It's highly OS-specific and, if there are things you don't want to do, you'll probably have to get the source code for it and take them out, in essence providing your own cut-down replacement for the object file.

Comment: its needed if im gonna use argc and argv, but im not going to actually, so i wanna remove this part.

Comment: @killercode, argument parsing is _one_ of the things it does. It may do many more. See my update.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely assume that your toolchain does not include code that is **not** needed and **could** safely be left out.

Make sure you compiled without debug information, and run `strip` on the resulting executable. Anything more intrusive than that requires intimate knowledge of your toolchain, and can result in rather strange behaviour that will be hard to debug - i.e., if you have to ask how it could be done, you shouldn't try to do it.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but as i pointed, tiny c compiler produces the code i write only, unlike gcc, which adds codes to parse command line arguments for argc and argv, i dont really need them, so i was wondering if there is a way to produce an exe without those, ty.

Comment: If the Tiny C compiler does not produce that code, you are compiling with a different option set (comparable to GCC's `-ffreestanding`). However, unless you know *exactly* what you are doing, this will result in a binary that doesn't help you any. (It wouldn't even start, for example.)