# ../mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/crt/crt1.c: No such file or directory

Tags: gdb

I am new to program world. I am learning C with Dev-cpp 5.6.1
I had a problem with my Debugger (GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1). When I debug any program, the debugger warned me

> Single stepping until exit from function main,
>   which has no line number information.

and

> __mingw_CRTStartup ()
>      at ../mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/crt/crt1.c:260
>   260     ../mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/crt/crt1.c: No such file or directory.

The problem happened before. I solved it by reinstalling Dev-Cpp (also reset old configure). But after a little time the problem came back again.

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    printf("Please give me number 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Please give me number 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("Sum = %d", a + b);
}
```

The debugger warned me:

```
C:\Users\Nam\Dropbox\code>gdb sum.exe
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "mingw32".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from C:\Users\Nam\Dropbox\code\sum.exe...done.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4016b3
(gdb) n
The program is not being run.
(gdb) r
Starting program: C:\Users\Nam\Dropbox\code/sum.exe
[New Thread 7148.0x1b6c]

Breakpoint 1, 0x004016b3 in main ()
(gdb) n
Single stepping until exit from function main,
which has no line number information.
Please give me number 1: 3
Please give me number 2: 4
Sum = 7__mingw_CRTStartup ()
    at ../mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/crt/crt1.c:260
260     ../mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/crt/crt1.c: No such file or di
rectory.
(gdb)
```

I couldn't know how to fix it.

Anyone helps me please :(. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> I couldn't know how to fix it.

I don't think it is necessary to fix it. You got this message since you had already returned from `main()` and now **you are not in your code**, it is mingw code that calls your `main()`. I did the same test as you and this is backtrace after finishing main:

```
10          printf("Sum = %d", a + b);
(gdb)
Sum = 311       }
(gdb) bt
#0  main () at t.c:11
(gdb) n
__mingw_CRTStartup () at ../mingw/crt1.c:250
250     ../mingw/crt1.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __mingw_CRTStartup () at ../mingw/crt1.c:250
#1  0x00401284 in mainCRTStartup () at ../mingw/crt1.c:264
(gdb) n
252     in ../mingw/crt1.c
(gdb) n
[Inferior 1 (process 1448) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

Again - you don't have to debug mingw startup code. Just give gdb command "continue" so that it can finish executing your process.

I have found source of this __mingw_CRTStartup here http://gitorious.org/mingw/mingw-runtime/source/be97f73714b4e267e5903fc9bdeb0f23fcc3ac8f:crt1.c#L200. You can take a look at what steps mingw library does after returning from main:

```
static void __attribute__((noreturn))
__mingw_CRTStartup (void)
{
int nRet;

 /* skipped some lines ... */

 nRet = main (_argc, _argv, environ);
/*
* Perform exit processing for the C library. This means
* flushing output and calling 'atexit' registered functions.
*/
_cexit ();
ExitProcess (nRet);
}
```

Some useful links:

1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/4988376/184968